# WHERE used with PARTITION BY postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have code:

```
SELECT br.name brewery_name, ibu, AVG(ibu) OVER (PARTITION BY 
       b.brewery_id ORDER BY ibu DESC)
FROM beers b
JOIN breweries br
ON b.brewery_id = br.brewery_id
WHERE ibu IS NOT NULL
```

Which gives me:

[image]

What I'm trying to get is to eliminate breweries that have less than 5 values for ibu (a lot of them have 1 or 2 - not visible on this snap). But I still want to stay with partition without grouping - so rows visible on the picture will stay the same.

I tried WHERE, HAVING, subquerying. But I get errors saying that I must group other values - for example that 'aggregate functions are not allowed in WHERE'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do a sub-query for valid brewery_ids you can then join on that list.  Like this:

```
SELECT br.name brewery_name, ibu, AVG(ibu) OVER (PARTITION BY 
       b.brewery_id ORDER BY ibu DESC)
FROM beers b
JOIN (
   SELECT brewery_id
   FROM beers
   GROUP BY brewery_id
   HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT ibu) >= 5
) X ON X.brewer_id = b.brewery_id 
JOIN breweries br ON b.brewery_id = br.brewery_id
WHERE ibu IS NOT NULL
```

The nice thing about a query like this is -- you can run the sub-query to validate it is limited to the IDs you want.  Then just plop it into your query.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the query you have an use window functions:

```
SELECT brewery_name, ibu, avg_ibu
FROM (SELECT br.name as brewery_name, ibu,
             AVG(ibu) OVER (PARTITION BY b.brewery_id ORDER BY ibu DESC) as avg_ibu,
             COUNT(ibu) OVER (PARTITION BY b.brewery_id) as cnt_ibu
      FROM beers b JOIN
           breweries br
          ON b.brewery_id = br.brewery_id
      WHERE ibu IS NOT NULL
     ) bb
WHERE cnt_ibu >= 5;
```

Comment: This one works as well and is easier to understand for me - thank you. It must be the COUNT part that I was missing in my query. I hope you don't mind me selecting Hogan's answer but he replied quicker and it also got me trying to figure out how X on X works. Thank you again!

Comment: @Coolkidscandie . . . As the OP, you can select whichever answer you want.  I think this would have better performance than using an additional join and aggregation.